# Possible reasons for "unsupported encryption type"-error in vagrant

Tags: vagrant

Every once in a while, when I use vagrant up, it crashes with an "unsupported encryption type"-error:

> The private key you're attempting to use with this Vagrant box uses
>   an unsupported encryption type. The SSH library Vagrant uses does not support
>   this key type. Please use `ssh-rsa` or `ssh-dss` instead. Note that
>   sometimes keys in your ssh-agent can interfere with this as well,
>   so verify the keys are valid there in addition to standard
>   file paths.

So far, I've always been able to fix this by rebuilding the machine, but now I have one that will throw this error no matter how often I rebuild it. The keys are generated by vagrant itself, and are standard rsa-keys. There are also no keys in ssh-agent. What else could be causing this error?

I'm using vagrant version 2.2.7
The machine was build with packer version 1.5.1
The provider is VirtualBox version 6.1.2

My other machines do currently not throw this error. Also, using vagrant ssh on the effected machine works perfectly fine.